# Draw the x-y-plane with the four quadrants marked in four different colors

Tags: color, diagrams, tikz-cd

I am trying to draw a colored diagram in Latex/Tikz and need some help. I would like the to draw the usual x-y-plane with axes marked in black and the four quadrants marked in four different colors. How can I do this?`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw[help lines, color=gray!30] (-4.9,-4.9) grid ;
\draw[->,thick] (-1.5,0)--(1.5,0) node[right]{$X$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,-1.5)--(0,1.5) node[above]{$Y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, at the moment there is just a basic x-y-axis. I would like to add colors, but I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using nor exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @JamesT Thanks for letting me know about the conventions of the site. I have entered the working basic draft. Is this sufficient?

Comment: Yes that is sufficient, as long as the code can compile so it can be copy and pasted and shows effort then it is fine :)

Comment: @JamesT Ok, great!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way using `\filldraw`:

[image]

I am certain others will have better solutions to this but still. `\yMax` is a value so that you can change how far the rectangle colours go out (`\yMax` at a value of 1.4 comes up just to the arrow points).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\yMax{1.5}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw[help lines, color=gray!30] (-4.9,-4.9) grid ;
\filldraw[red] (0.02,0.02) rectangle (\yMax,\yMax);
\filldraw[yellow] (-0.02,-0.02) rectangle (-\yMax,-\yMax);
\filldraw[blue] (-0.02,0.02) rectangle (-\yMax,\yMax);
\filldraw[green] (0.02,-0.02) rectangle (\yMax,-\yMax);

\draw[->,thick] (-1.5,0)--(1.5,0) node[right]{$X$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,-1.5)--(0,1.5) node[above]{$Y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to change the positions of the X and Y labels then use the `yshift`, `xshift` arguments to `node`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\yMax{1.5}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw[help lines, color=gray!30] (-4.9,-4.9) grid ;
\filldraw[red] (0.02,0.02) rectangle (\yMax,\yMax);
\filldraw[yellow] (-0.02,-0.02) rectangle (-\yMax,-\yMax);
\filldraw[blue] (-0.02,0.02) rectangle (-\yMax,\yMax);
\filldraw[green] (0.02,-0.02) rectangle (\yMax,-\yMax);

\draw[->,thick] (-1.5,0)--(1.5,0) node[above,xshift=-0.2cm]{$X$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,-1.5)--(0,1.5) node[right,yshift=-0.2cm]{$Y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the diagram. Is it possible to change the placing of the labels X and Y so that are above/below the arrow instead of at the tip?

Comment: @JakeWetlock I have updated my answer, use `xshift` and `yshift` :)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Something to get started.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %\draw[help lines, color=gray!30] (-4.9,-4.9) grid ;
        \draw[->,thick] (-1.5,0)--(1.5,0) node[right]{$X$};
        \draw[->, thick] (0,-1.5)--(0,1.5) node[above]{$Y$};
        
        \begin{scope}[x=1.5 cm, y=1.5 cm, opacity=0.5]
            \fill[violet] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
            \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (-1,1);
            \fill[green] (0,0) rectangle (-1,-1);
            \fill[orange] (0,0) rectangle (1,-1);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another one, adding all the quadrants in a `\foreach` loop:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[count=\ii from 0]\i in {blue,red,green,yellow}
  \fill[\i!20,rotate=90*\ii] (0,0) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
\draw[->,thick] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[right]{$X$};
\draw[->,thick] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above]{$Y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

[image]

Minimal simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[green] (-2,-2) rectangle (0,0);
        \fill[yellow] (0,-2) rectangle (2,0);
        \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
        \fill[cyan] (-2,0) rectangle (0,2);
        \draw[-latex] (-2,0)--(2.2,0) node[right] () {$x$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-2)--(0,2.2) node[right] () {$y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```